# show all subplots values when hovering in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following code that produces the following plot with plotly:

```
def save_plots(train_dir: str, checkpoints_data: defaultdict, set_name: str) -> None:
    def generate_plot(models: Tuple[str], metric_value: Tuple[Union[float, int]], metric: str) -> go.Figure:
        metric_fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=models, y=metric_value, mode='lines+markers', name=metric))
        metric_fig.update_layout(title=f'Models vs {metric}', xaxis_title='Models', yaxis_title=metric)
        return metric_fig

    _saving_path = f'{train_dir}/checkpoints_analysis/{set_name}'

    _metrics = [_metric for _metric in checkpoints_data.keys() if 'avg' in _metric]
    _num_plots = len(_metrics)

    fig = make_subplots(
        rows=_num_plots, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, subplot_titles=[f'Models vs {_metric}' for _metric in _metrics]
    )

    for _idx, _metric in enumerate(_metrics, start=1):
        _models, _metric_values = sort_by_models(checkpoints_data, _metric)
        _models_name = tuple([Path(_m).stem for _m in _models])
        _fig = generate_plot(_models_name, _metric_values, _metric)
        fig.add_trace(_fig.data[0], row=_idx, col=1)
        fig.update_yaxes(title_text=_metric, row=_idx, col=1)

    fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified", legend_traceorder="normal")
    fig.update_xaxes(showspikes=True, tickangle=45)
    fig.update_yaxes(showspikes=True)
    # fig.update_traces(xaxis='x2')
    fig.write_html(f'{_saving_path}/metrics.html')
    return
```

If I unmark `# fig.update_traces(xaxis='x2')` I get the hovering on all the plots but the x labels disapear.

I wish to have the hover on all the plots and keep the x labels and on top of that I want the hover to show all the y values from the different subplots

Is there an easy way to accomplish that?

Adding the data used:

```
{"model": ["/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_420000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_600000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_390000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_300000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_60000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_360000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_150000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_120000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_180000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_210000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_90000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_570000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_30000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_270000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_510000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_540000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_480000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_450000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_330000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_0.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model_240000.pth", "/home/davids/Desktop/cosine_warm_scheduler/checkpoints/model.pth"], "avg_loss": [0.0036763183306902647, 0.004363081883639097, 0.003417815314605832, 0.004102202598005533, 0.004445521626621485, 0.0026747453957796097, 0.004204410128295422, 0.0036755481269210577, 0.004840160254389048, 0.00404144823551178, 0.004303190391510725, 0.003531521651893854, 0.0047956290654838085, 0.002990592969581485, 0.0036763660609722137, 0.0037452855613082647, 0.0033208306413143873, 0.003690345911309123, 0.005245397333055735, 0.1328689306974411, 0.003326127305626869, 0.004363081883639097], "avg_psnr": [41.59144028549018, 42.95730374601708, 42.29179534861813, 41.7167287111758, 40.821101800877315, 40.73124200110699, 40.48821755394471, 41.79024202502962, 41.228948663357315, 42.45664979731934, 40.042352757724636, 42.692219419740404, 39.748576935512126, 41.086776097763355, 42.39727754080589, 40.776704640286944, 42.93828182603682, 41.483766701559176, 38.66716049534964, 17.72983360448493, 41.09546018074682, 42.95730374601708], "avg_ssim": [0.9439684591886041, 0.9624857520332679, 0.9498272045085221, 0.9471334112749001, 0.9397458469045343, 0.9070406835707514, 0.9323768512422683, 0.9460773813291695, 0.9413555045668902, 0.9588148465571097, 0.928919181344386, 0.9552519862884038, 0.9315641649298317, 0.9222171210404341, 0.9500127185784926, 0.9277716428181317, 0.9551910467741089, 0.9388119192967415, 0.9345200268674203, 0.10216873303094673, 0.9358614313888907, 0.9624857520332679]}
```

[image]

Comment: A question equivalent to your request has been posted in the [plotly community](https://community.plotly.com/t/unified-hovermode-with-sublots/37606). It is possible to just extend the spike line, all hover seems to be unsupported at this time.